# Javascript to end ajax-loader.gif

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I have an animated gif that's supposed to run until a page completes loading.  The gif is being handled in the stylesheet, and I want a bit of javascript to change the background element when the page loads to hide the gif.  Here's the code:

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $('#confirm .checkout-heading').css("background", "#fff url('../image/ajax-loader.gif') 98% 50% no-repeat");
    $.ajax({
    url: 'checkout/checkout.php',
    success: function(data) {},
    failure: function(){},
    complete: function(){ $('#confirm .checkout-heading').css("background", "#fff"); }
    });
</script>
```

style:

```
#confirm .checkout-heading {
    background: #fff url('../image/ajax-loader.gif') 98% 50% no-repeat;
```

I've tried debugging, and I've determined that it's stuck on the `complete: function()`, but I'm not js savvy enough to know how to fix this.  Thanks for any help...

Comment: what do you mean "it's stuck"

Comment: Can you try doing a .hide() of the "confirm" element in the complete eventhandler? The other option is to use the [.ajaxStart and .ajaxComplete handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Comment: @scibuff "SyntaxError: function statement requires a name" according to my debugger...

Comment: @Scorpion-Prince I really need to see example code - I know next to nothing about writing javascript...

Comment: Just FYI: It's would be much better if you'd define your styles in CSS file and instead of manipulating inline styles using jQuery, just add and remove CSS classes. Much easier to maintain your code.

Comment: And while you're getting a **Syntax error**... Which line does it point to? because looking at your code it surely doesn't seem that anything would be wrong with it. So I suspect there must be something else wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript code seems fine, although makes it hard to maintain your code and styles, because you're mixing both... Anyway. Your **Syntax error** must be pointing somewhere else, because based on your code, nothing *should* be wrong with it.

### I suggest you do it this way

This will make it much easier to maintain your code, because styles will be completely separate from code. Your code will merely manipulate CSS classes.

Have two CSS definitions related to this:

```
#confirm .checkout-heading {
    background-color: #fff;
}

#confirm .checkout-heading.loading
    background-image: url('../image/ajax-loader.gif');
    background-position: 98% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And then write your Javascript code as:

```
var el = $("#confirm .checkout-heading").addClass("loading");
$.ajax({
    url: 'checkout/checkout.php',
    success: function(data) {},
    failure: function() {},
    complete: function() {
        el.removeClass("loading");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Scorpion-Prince said, try hiding the spinner on complete. If I had a unique id on my gif container it would be something like this.

```
complete: function(){ $('#myGifContainer').hide(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class like below:

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $('#confirm .checkout-heading').css("background", "#fff url('../image/ajax-loader.gif') 98% 50% no-repeat");
    $.ajax({
    url: 'checkout/checkout.php',
    success: function(data) {},
    failure: function(){},
    complete: function(){ $('#confirm .checkout-heading').addClass("fffClass"); }
    });
</script>
```

then add in css

```
.fffClass{
background: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of examples of using ajaxStart and ajaxStop handlers

```
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() {   
   // Setup the ajax indicator  
   $('body').append('<div id="ajaxBusy"><p><img src="images/loading.gif"></p></div>');      
   $('#ajaxBusy').css({    
       display:"none",    
       margin:"0px",    
       paddingLeft:"0px",    
       paddingRight:"0px",    
       paddingTop:"0px",    
       paddingBottom:"0px",    
       position:"absolute",    
       right:"3px",    
       top:"3px",    
       width:"auto"    
    });
 });

// Ajax activity indicator bound to ajax start/stop document events
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){   
    $('#ajaxBusy').show(); 
}).ajaxStop(function(){   
    $('#ajaxBusy').hide();
});
```